# How to get the address for the next merged cell?

Tags: excel, vba

How I use the loop method to get the address for the other **Test**?

I have Test3 and Test4 also.

[image: Excel Print Screen]

Comment: Ahh merged cells.....Excel's worst nightmare =). Can you show us your code please.

Comment: @JvdV I tried to use Rows.count method to get the address but failed

Comment: Are the merged cells in discussion consecutive? I mean isn't it possible that unmerged cells to exist in between?

Comment: @FaneDuru it should be consecutive because it is an attendance record.

Comment: And you need to find the next merged cell address. Next against what? Against "A1"? Against selection? Do you need to enumerate all merged cells of A:A addresses/values?

Comment: @FaneDuru Ya, in **column A** I have many records with merged cells. Now I need the address for each merged cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My two cents:

```
Sub Test()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Dim lr As Long

lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For x = 1 To lr
    Debug.Print ws.Cells(x, 1).Value
    If ws.Cells(x, 1).MergeCells Then
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(x, 1).MergeArea.Address
        x = x - 1 + ws.Cells(x, 1).MergeArea.Rows.Count
    Else
        Debug.Print ws.Cells(x, 1).Address
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the address for each merged cell! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.MergeArea` property for this:

```
Sub test1()
    Set cell_after_merged = Range("A1").MergeArea.Cells(Range("A1").MergeArea.Rows.Count).Offset(1)
    Debug.Print cell_after_merged
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
Test2
```

Comment: How can I get **Test3**?

Comment: If we're talking about Test3 only, then `Set cell_after_merged = cell_after_merged.MergeArea.Cells(cell_after_merged.MergeArea.Rows.Count).Offset(1)`. If we talk about all subsequent ones, we need to implement the loop